# Calling attributes from classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am playing around with classes and I want to do the following:

```
class Hi (object):
     def __init__(self, bloop):
          self.bloop = bloop
thing = Hi("bloop")
name = input("Input a thing") # Let`s assume you input thing
print(name.bloop)
```

What I want it to do is for it to `print "bloop"` because you entered `thing` and it gets `bloop` from `thing` kinda like `thing.bloop`.

Comment: Tried to correct equal signs and quotations. If anything is missing, feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing `thing` in a `dict`:

```
class Hi:
    def __init__(self, bloop):
        self.bloop = bloop
things = {'thing': Hi('bloop')}

name = input("Input a thing") # Let`s assume you input 'thing'
try:
    print(things[name].bloop)
except KeyError:
    print("Sorry, I dont know that thing :(")
```

There are, of course, other ways to call an attribute of a class. You could implement a `__call__()` method, which allows you to call the class instance like a function, and in your case return `.bloop`:

```
class Hi:
    def __init__(self, bloop):
         self.bloop = bloop
    def __call__(self):
        return self.bloop

things = {'thing': Hi('bloop')}
name = input("Input a thing") # Let`s assume you input 'thing'
try:
    print(things[name]())
except KeyError:
    print("Sorry, I dont know that thing :(")
```

This way, you can rename your attribute later, or return another attribute (or do something entirely different altogether), without having to replace `.bloop` in your main python file.

A third way, which directly relates to your question's title `calling attributes from[of] classes in Python`: you can use the `@Property` decorator to make your `.bloop` attribute callable like a function like so:

```
class Hi:
    def __init__(self, bloop):
         self.bloop = bloop
    @Property
    def bloop():
        return self.bloop

    @bloop.setter
    def bloop(self, new_value)
        self.bloop = new_value


things = {'thing': Hi('bloop')}
name = input("Input a thing") # Let`s assume you input 'thing'
try:
    print(things[name].bloop())
except KeyError:
    print("Sorry, I dont know that thing :(")
```

To fully understand the `Property` decorator, [I recommend this article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property).

Btw, according to the `tags` on your question, you're using `Python3.x` - you don't have to declare that your class inherits from `Object` in Python3 and later.